# X11 app no longer opening since 10.10.3

Tags: macos, terminal, x11

After upgrading to 10.10.3 X11 applications are not opening anymore from the terminal.

The `X11` symlink in `/usr` is correct

```
$ ls -l /usr/X11
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 Aug  7  2014 /usr/X11 -> /opt/X11
```

I reinstalled XQuartz (2.7.7)

`$DISPLAY` is set

```
$ echo $DISPLAY 
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.mXmpHGFD7q/org.macports:0
```

Opening applications from the X11 menu (e.g. Applications -> Terminal) works.

Opening them from the Terminal app does nothing. Applications (e.g. xterm, emacs, ...) are stuck

What could I try?

**Update**

If I disconnect an external display then even the application opened via X11 menu are not working anymore. I have to close X11 and reopen it.

Comment: Try adding the app XQuartz. Worked for me.

Comment: As stated "I reinstalled XQuartz (2.7.7)", I already have the latest XQuartz version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the XQuartz package on MacOS Forge. I personally have had problems with Macports XQuartz and Yosemite, however the standard installer works perfectly for me. Or maybe try using the xorg-server package from Macports.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had before and what I re-installed.

Comment: @Matteo Try running the installer or Macports install in verbose and look out for any errors

Comment: Hi, your answer gave me the idea to try the opposite. Instead of using the MacOS Forge package I installed xorg-server from MacPorts and it now works like a charm. I'll award the bounty, but then update your answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Many thanks! Ok, I have to wait 13h hours for the bounty ...

Comment: @Matteo Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll assign the bounty as soon as it is allowed.

Comment: I opened another bounty. I'll be able to assign it in 23 hours sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with pixman compatibility...

```
$/usr/X11/bin/X

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
  Reason: Incompatible library version: X11.bin requires version 33.0.0 or later, but libpixman-1.0.dylib provides version 25.0.0
```

Comment: I don't get the error. Opening `/usr/X11/bin/X` just starts X11 (as expected). But then no application can be opened.

Comment: Wrong Answer for the bounty, whatever I'll grant another 100 to sebastien ...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems since OSX 10, now using XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2) and when the X11 Terminal windows opens (the app freezes at this point) I simply close it by typing 'exit' at the prompt. After that, it all works fine for me.

Don't try and install the automatic update version - simply download it stand-alone.

Answer (score -2):

for MAC  on v 2.7.11
https://www.xquartz.org/releases/XQuartz-2.7.10_rc5.html

```
sudo mv /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib{,.bak}
sudo cp /opt/X11/lib{/flat_namespace,}/libXt.6.dylib
```